# How do I disable extension errors from being displayed in the Firefox console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools, lastpass

I keep getting errors from LastPass and some other extensions in the JS console (Firefox Devtools). Screen from one of those errors below.

In my about:config `extensions.logging.enabled` is set to `false`. The console is on the main thread so not sure why I see them.

[image: DevTools JS Console]

Comment: I'm running into this problem as well